# How to test a long method in separate methods in JUnit?

Tags: junit, mockito

I have a long public method. It clearly separates logically into different parts. What I could do to test it would be something like

```
@Test
public void shouldWork() {
    //Execute target method

    //This is a comment hinting that now the first step is verified
    //Verify first step

    //This is a comment hinting that now the second step is verified
    //Verify second step
}
```

I don't like this at all since it will only show a failure in this gigantic method if any individual part had an error. It seems reasonable to write separate test methods for every step. Then I'm facing the following situation:

```
@Test
public void testFirstStep() {
    //Execute target method
    //Verify first step
}

@Test
public void testSecondStep() {
    //Execute target method
    //Verify second step
}
```

Here I have the problem that my verifications for both steps have the form `verify(myMockitoMock).myMethod(myArg)` (multiple times on the same mock). Since these verifications do respect the order of calls I'm fine for the first step but the test for the second step assumes that all the verifications of the first step already happened. Logically it would be fine to do

```
@Test
public void testFirstStep() {
    //Execute target method
    executeVerificationsForFirstStep(myMock);
}

@Test
public void testSecondStep() {
    //Execute target method
    executeVerificationsForFirstStep(myMock);
    //Verify second step
}

private void executeVerificationsForFirstStep(Mock myMock) {
    //Verifications for first step on myMock
}
```

However then the test for the second test will fail if some verification fails for the first step.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you should split the huge method into more granular, easily testable ones. Possibly extract some classes.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to split your methods into several submethods and write a test method for each one of the submethods.
And in the end you can test the main method that calls your submethods in order to make sure that all your submethods are working fine together and this will be like a system testing (integration testing)

Answer (score 0):

First write the test that makes you unhappy...

```
@Test
public void shouldWork() {
    //Execute target method

    //This is a comment hinting that now the first step is verified
    //Verify first step

    //This is a comment hinting that now the second step is verified
    //Verify second step
}
```

Then ensure that it passes and verifies something useful. Bear in mind the rules of thumb that a class should have one responsibility and a method should do *one* thing. Extract the obvious methods, which you can already see. Re-run the test and ensures that it passes.

Now evaluate what the class and methods are doing relative to those two rules of thumb. Does the class have one responsibility? If not, then think about what the responsibilities are and write some tests to bring new classes into existence to meet those responsibilities. If you work in this way (TDD), I suspect that your methods will do *one* thing more often without even thinking much about that rule.